# using sqlcmd to save a table query to CSV, cannot re-import back into the same table definition?

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, bulkinsert

I have an extremely large database I need to send to the developer, the table has over 120million rows.  the developer says he only needs about 10,000 or so rows so I was going to use the sqlcmd -S  -d  -Q "select top 10000 * from table" -s "," -o "C:\temp\filename.csv"
I decided rather than truncate immediately I would script out the table, rename and test bulk inserting, I tried using 
bulk insert tablename from 'c:\temp\filename.csv'
with (
fieldterminator = ',',
rowterminator = '\n'
)

this ends in "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1..." error.  I also tried in import/export wizard and it fails for the same problem (truncation).  increasing the size of the field lengths, solves the problem but I really am having problems understanding why I need to do this. Its the same data from the same table, it should bulk insert right back in?!?
 also the problem is happening on every column in the table and by varying lengths, so there is no column with the same number of chars I have to add.  all the columns are varchar data type.  could the sqlcmd be inserting some kind of corruption in the file?  I have tried to look for a problem, I also tried rtrim(ltrim(columname)) to make sure there is no whitespace but I'm not sure this is how it works.  I'm using sql server 2012 if this helps.
thanks

Comment: SQLCmd output does not format the results for import, it formats it for display. If you view the results from SQLCmd output you will see that it includes extra text and a lot of spacing besides the data (change your query two a single record (top 1), open the csv with a text editor and the problem will be immediately clear). For a solution look at the BCP utility (@BrianStork's solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into BCP Queryout and BULK INSERT options. Use NATIVE format if you're going from SQL to SQL.

(BCP is command-line):

```
bcp "select top(10000) * from table" queryout "OUTPUTFILENAME.DAT" -S serverInstanceName -d databaseName -T -n
```

The Bulk Insert command is SQL (not command line):

```
bulk insert table from 'path\and\OUTPUTFILENAME.DAT' with (keepidentity,datafiletype = 'native');
```

(If the table doesn't have an identity, you can eliminate `keepidentity,`

Comment: Thank you, turns out my resolution was simpler than that.  I simply performed an "insert into ... select top 10000..." and my problem was solved.  but I agree the way I was doing it before was wrong and for larger bulk operations I need to try doing it the way you suggest.  This is something for me to practice thanks!